# JQuery tab content displayed at bottom on resizing window

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using jQuery tabs plugin in my application and am facing some resizing issue with it. This is the html -

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="view">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#t1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#t2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#t3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#t4">Tab 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="container" id="t1">Content A
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="t2">Content B
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="t3">Content C
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="t4">Content D
    </div>
</div>
```

When I view this page in full window, it is properly displayed, but when I resize the window to lesser width, the div controls are displaying below the tabs and not next to them. As you can see, as the size is already less of the JSFiddle window, the content is displayed at the bottom. I want it to be properly resized alongside the tab menu.

Yes, I can reduce the width to say 10%, but I want it to be 100% to start with and then resize automatically. How shall I fix this issue?

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/241t6met/1/) is the JSFiddle link.

Comment: what is the smallest width you want that display before it becomes fully responsive via bootstrap

Comment: Atleast the width of small devices - 768px

Comment: OK @sam then follow the instructions below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is under bootstrap; a starting point would be to use the bootstrap responsive grid system like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/241t6met/6/)

```
<ul class="col-md-x">....
<div class=" col-md-x" id="t1">...
```

Then decide at want point you browser window you want it to go to the bottom, even if its at 480px and use [grid options media query](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) to customize your css.

Comment: Wrapped in cols like this - 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <ul>..
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <div class="container" id="t1">Content A..
    </div>
</div>

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because your "tabs" container is 8em wide (an absolute size) and your "content" container is 90% wide (a relative size). When the window is full-screen, the 10% of the screen left for the tabs is >8em so the tabs fit to the left of the content. When the window is smaller, that 10% is <8em so the content div drops below the tabs because there isn't room for it.

The easiest solution to this is to make the content container a static width and float it left. Given how the .tabs() plugin works, you cannot give the content container a relative width and the tabs container a static one. They must both be of one type or the other.

The other option is to give the tabs container a relative width as well to take up the remaining space (10% in this case).